# AB/Hypothesis testing in multiple groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, frequentist, ab-test

Let's say I have two variants of my website and I would like to know which variant generates more revenue. This website operates in multiple countries and I will choose a variant for all countries at the same time once the test is finished. I set up an ab test, sending half of the traffic of each country to each variant. I'm using classical frequentist hypothesis test, testing if the mean revenue increases. Let's say alpha=0.05 and beta=0.8.

I want to avoid distortions like Simpsons's Paradox, so I analyse the results for the countries separately.

Let's say I find some countries to pass the test and some others don't. How can I deal with this and reach conclusions?

I've tried to treat the amount of tests that passed as a binomial random variable, but the interpretation was hard and didn't seem to make sense. Any thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps I'm unclear.  If some countries fail to reject the null, where is the issue?

Comment: If it fails in all countries, I would reject. If it passes in all countries, I would accept. I would like to know where the middle ground is

Comment: The conclusion that the variant produces more revenue that the original in some countries but not all is a completely legitimate conclusion.  There is no need for an "all or nothing" approach

Comment: But under a alpha=0.05 we expect 5% of the tests to fail to reject the null hypothesis even if the alternative hypothesis is false, right? So even if all are better, we will fail sometimes

Comment: That is only when the null hypothesis is true. In general, if you are going to perform lots of tests, you're going to make at least one error.

Comment: That's what I said, right? Even if the alternative is right, we will fail to reject the null a couple of times if we do many tests. My question is: how many failures to reject can be tolerated?